# "Types are not supported by current JavaScript version" in PhpStorm

Tags: typescript, vue.js, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm working in PhpStorm on a Vue 2 / TypeScript project where whenever I want to include return types on functions I get "Types are not supported by current JavaScript version":

[image: Types are not supported by current JavaScript version]

On "Preferences > Languages and Frameworks > JavaScript", I have `ECMAScript 6+` selected:

[image: selected]

I've tried restarting the IDE to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have type annotations. You need to use Flow or TypeScript or (potentially) other things that allow for using types.

Comment: just modify file extension. replace `js` with `ts`

Comment: Such a weird error message really. I mean, it is as if types are just about to be supported in the nearest version of JavaScript.

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky I agree. VSCode has the better one `Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, apparently I was misled by the wording of the error message. Simply adding `<script lang="ts">` inside my vue files has fixed it.

Comment: exactly - without `lang` attribute, the `<script>` language is assumed to be javascript, thus the message

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, but it happened because I was writing Typescript code in a `.js` file instead of `.ts` file.

1. Rename `.js` to `.ts`
2. Make sure you have the Javascript language version set to **ECMAScript 6+** under **Languages & Frameworks** > **Javascript** in your Jetbrain IDE.